# How to change right click options on Group in AppCode?

Tags: intellij-idea, appcode

I want to move `Swift Type` and `Swift File` options to the top, but I can't find it `Preferences / Menus and Tooblars`.

[image: Right Click Popup]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Intellij IDEA, but I hope it helps you:

You can try `Apperance & Behavior / Menus and Tooblar / Project view Popup Menu / New`
[image]